# Solution To Stop Cat Excreting In My Front Yard

Tags: cats, behavior, feces

I have been suffering a problem since last few weeks. I took my cat out for some playtime and he led me to another stray cat's feces in my yard's grass & now this has been very frequent. I've tried to cover the feces with sand to deter the cat but that has no luck. How do i prevent stray cats from excreting over my premises and how to remove the current feces in the yard